# Compiling Aseprite from source code. Problem with compiling skia library

Tags: skia

Im trying to compile Aseprite from github's source code. 
When I type in console:

````
 gn gen out/Release --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false target_cpu=""x64"" cc=""clang"" cxx=""clang++"" clang_win=""c:\deps\llvm"" win_vc=""G:\Visual Studio\VC"```
````

I get an error:

> ERROR Need exactly one build directory to generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two quotes at the end "" :

```
...Community\VC"""
```

SEE:
https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md